# Elbow Ligament/Tendon Injury Diagnosis-Aid?

Tags: tendinopathy, treatment, diagnostics, diagnosis

When a patient comes into the office with what seems like an injury to the ligaments/tendons around the elbow, **what are the "exercises" that the physician uses in order to identify or pinpoint the injured tissue structure?**
What are these "exercises" called? What are the actual individual exercises/tests that are used called? What is the method of diagnosis using this type of method called?

e.g. I go into the doctor's office with an injury to the medial collateral ligament, so the physician has me apply pressure to his arms in certain directions/angles with my arms placed in certain positions in order to see which "exercise" triggers pain/discomfort or reveals weaknesses. There seemed to be around ~3-5 of them.

Please help me make this question better in any way possible.